# Implicit super constructor AbstractNcssCountRule() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor

Tags: java, plugins, pmd

I would like to test if a Specified Method exists. And I have done the programmation with some help from this website. Yeah, I have written 2 interfaces and a class who implement the interfaces.

Here are parts of the codes:

```
public class TestMethod extends AbstractNcssCountRule implements UpSearch,
    JudgeResult {

    public Object search(ASTMethodDeclaration node, Object data) {
        return super.visit(node, data);
    }

    public Object judge(ASTMethodDeclaration node, Object data) {
        if ((node.jjtGetChild(1) instanceof ASTMethodDeclarator && ( node
            .jjtGetChild(1)).getImage().equals("isDirty"))) {
            System.out.println("There it is.");
        }
    }
}
```

However,there is a small bug. When I move my cursor to the name of the class, it tells:
**Implicit super constructor AbstractNcssCountRule() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to implement all the methods from both the interface

Comment: More details? I don't understand.

Comment: I have writeen 2 interfaces.

Comment: In fact I have implemented all the methods. I think.

Comment: check your code that you have implemented all the methods of both interface in your Class "TestMethod"

Comment: the 2 interfaces are package com.chanbarry.pmd;

public interface UpSearch {
 public Object search();
}  package com.chanbarry.pmd;

public interface JudgeResult {
 public Object judge();
}

Comment: I think I have implemented the 2 interfaces.

Comment: Buddy, your methods in interface are non-parameterized. and you are implementing parametrized methods in your class. edit your interface code and specify a proper parameters to your methods that you are going to use in your class.

Comment: then try defining a default constructor or parameterized constructor with some arguments.

Comment: sorry i don't really understand.

Comment: "The type TestMethod must implement the inherited abstract method Rule.hasProperty(String)."

Answer (score 0):

It's the problem of Version.
Just delete one version and modify the codes a little.